# Retrieve the value of an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

hi i have an object as follows:

```
const state = {
     working: "I am currently working",
     studying: " I am currently studying",
}
```

I want to be able to retrieve the text "I am currently working" or "I am currently studying" from this object if there is a change in state.

My code is currently as follows:

```
const currentState = "working";
{currentState === "working" ? state.working : state.studying}
```

I was wondering if there was a better way in which i can retrieve the text without using tenary, i also do not mind using an array.

Comment: You can access using the dynamic access syntax. Something like this: `state[currentState]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `const` outside your component and use a boolean state in your component:

```
const message = {
  working: 'I am currently working',
  studying: 'I am currently studying',
}

export function App() {
  const [working, setWorking] = useState(false) // or true

  return (
    <>
      <div>{working ? message.working : message.studying}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setWorking((w) => !w)}>Click</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `currentState` is always either "**working**" or "**studying**" you could do

```
state[currentState]
```

which then will give you the corresponding value.

You can put object attributes in the square brackets after the object-name to select the wished value.